# The best way to check existence of filtered rows in Cassandra? by user-defined aggregate?

Tags: cassandra, aggregate-functions

I have a Cassandra table,

```
CREATE TABLE read_locks (
    parent_path text,
    filename text,
    instance text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((parent_path, filename), instance)
);
```

Logically I want to check the existence of any locks on a file by the following statement:

```
select count(*)>0 as result from read_locks where parent_path='...' and filename='...';
```

Of course, I have at least 2 implementations.

```
select count(*) as result from read_locks where parent_path='...' and filename='...';
```

and then to use other code, i.e. C++, to check the value of result.

Or

```
select * from read_locks where parent_path='...' and filename='...';
```

and then to use other code, i.e. C++, to check the bool value of the following statement:

```
cass_iterator_next(rows)
```

I am not sure which is better.

And I guess there is a user-defined aggregate function to do so, but I couldn't figure out.

Please share your comments.

Thank you in advance,
Ying

Comment: if you can have many instances (>1000) and all you care about is whether a lock exists for any instance, you should avoid count. Count will cause all the data to be read in at once, which for large amounts of rows will cause issues. At least with * you can utilise paging to control how much data is read per page.

Comment: Good suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you only care if there are any locks, and now how many locks there are, then it's probably more efficient to add a limit clause like this:

```
SELECT * FROM read_locks WHERE parent_path='...' and filename='...' LIMIT 1;
```

If that returns a row, then you know there is at least one lock on the file, and if it returns nothing, then there are no locks on the file.

Comment: Good suggestion. Thanks.